# capture UIScrollView into UIImage while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to mirror what is happening in a view on an iPad on an external screen.

```
func startMirroring() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func tick() {
    let snapshot = someView.snapshotImage()
    placeSomewhereElse(image: snapshot)
}

extension UIView {
    func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }
}
```

**The problem**

Scrolling in a scrollview will only be reflected in the snapshot after scrolling has ended. I believe the scrollview is not really updating it's view hierarchy and layout during scrolling for efficiency. I need to however capture it during scrolling.

I tried:

- afterScreenUpdates: true

In scrollViewDidScroll:

- setNeedsDisplay()
- layoutIfNeeded()
- setNeedsLayout()

Is it possible to capture the scrollviews during scrolling?

Edit to clarify:

Hierarchy:

- UIWindow <- I wanna snapshot this
- ----UIView
- --------UIScrollView <- i have no knowledge of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove Timer and call startMirroring() method in scrollViewDidScroll, I have tried your scenario and got continuous monitoring of scrollview,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrolling")
    startMirroring()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrolling ends")
}

func startMirroring() {
    imgView.image = scrollView.snapshotImage()
}

extension UIView {
  func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
      drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
      let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return snapshotImage
  }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: I want to capture an entire view that 'might' contain scrollviews and not just specific scrollviews. I can use this to handle scrollviews in the view hierarchy differently so this is already great, but ideally i wanna do it without any knowledge about the view hierarchy.

Comment: Please keep any View in the place of  scrollView.snapshotImage() (ex: someView.snapshotImage())  , its working fine for me.

Comment: While this is not the ideal solution, triggering a capture within scrollViewDidScroll does work so I'll accept this answer.